# How to retry upload to server in Android

Tags: java, android, networking, timer

I have an application that receives text messages with a BroadcastReceiver. It tries to upload them to a server and if it fails it has to retry.

I wonder which would be a good way to retry uploading. Should I use some kind of timer that fires an event like a BroadcastReceiver to retry sending messages every so often (how?) or something else?

Comment: any logcat errors? plz post here

Comment: What do you mean? I was thinking errors in general. For example, if the phone doesn't have an internet connection, it has to try it later.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Android AlarmManager system. You can schedule a service to keep trying to upload your data in case you get a timeout, like d.i.v.a said, or any other IO problem in the first try.

Please refer to: https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html to learn a bit more about alarms.

Another useful link:

- http://khurramitdeveloper.blogspot.com.br/2013/06/android-alarm-manager-to-start-service.html

If you don't want to use the system alarm for some reason, you can also try to use Thread.sleep() inside a "retry loop", assuming you're using a service, AsyncTask, etc. (Don't call Thread.sleep in the main thread!)

Answer (score 0):

> It's worth if u get the timeout and hit the upload again if extends
>   this time out..

```
DefaultHttpClient h;
// ...
Log.d(TAG, "http.socket.timeout: " +
      h.getParams().getParameter("http.socket.timeout"));
Log.d(TAG, "http.connection.timeout: "
      + h.getParams().getParameter("http.connection.timeout"));
```

Comment: What are you saying? I want to retry sending the messages to the server after a certain time.

Comment: i m saying to retry after this timeout.. instead of setting a timer and retry as u said

Answer (score 0):

you can try to use **JobScheduler** to schedule your upload task.

if the task fails, just calls jobFinished(mJobParam, needsReschedule),your task will be rescheduled

if your want to set the retry policy or the retry interval to wait when the task fails,you can set setBackoffCriteria(long initialBackoffMillis, int backoffPolicy)

[AndroidTaskScheduling docs](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidTaskScheduling/article.html)

i hope this can help you.